# Pasting Values To/From a Calculation Model

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a Database worksheet (`SoapUI - CollisionsSingle`) that have around 1500 records and 38 columns of data per record. I have a VBA script that copies the records into a algorithm worksheet (`COL_STpremcalc`) and then copies the results back to the database worksheet. However it takes around 1-2 minutes to perform 1 record, and all but breaks my laptop to the point I can't do anything while it runs.

```
Sub SingleRating()
Dim i As Long
Dim iteration As Variant
Dim seleciton As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("SoapUI - CollisionsSingle")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("COL_STpremcalc")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

iteration = 0
iteration = InputBox("Please Select Row Iteration", "", "1")
seleciton = iteration + 3

    For i = 4 To seleciton

        ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("D" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("E" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B5").Value = ws1.Range("F" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("G" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E3").Value = ws1.Range("H" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E4").Value = ws1.Range("I" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E5").Value = ws1.Range("J" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E6").Value = ws1.Range("K" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G3").Value = ws1.Range("L" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G4").Value = ws1.Range("M" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G5").Value = ws1.Range("N" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("J3").Value = ws1.Range("O" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("J6").Value = ws1.Range("P" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C9:E9").Value = ws1.Range("Q" & i, "S" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C10:E10").Value = ws1.Range("T" & i, "V" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C11:E11").Value = ws1.Range("W" & i, "Y" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C12:E12").Value = ws1.Range("Z" & i, "AB" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C13:E13").Value = ws1.Range("AC" & i, "AE" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C14:E14").Value = ws1.Range("AF" & i, "AH" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C15:E15").Value = ws1.Range("AI" & i, "AK" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("C16:E16").Value = ws1.Range("AL" & i, "AN" & i).Value

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        ws1.Range("AO" & i).Value = ws2.Range("M4").Value

        Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & (i - 1) & "/" & iteration
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

The reason I don't just do the calculation in the database worksheet is that there is about 100+ calculations that happen before the final results and the calculations are complex.

The calculation happens almost instantly, it is the copying of the data back and forth that I believe is slowing the whole thing down.

Is there a way to make this more efficient to the point it would only take around 20-30 minutes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Excel is not a database

I cannot stress this strongly enough. Excel has many excellent uses, but please don't ever get in the habit of thinking that it is a viable alternative to a proper Database.

---

### Never assume that you know where the performance bottleneck is

If you could accurately forecast where a performance bottleneck would be, then you wouldn't have an unbearably slow Macro in the first place.

Rule #1 of performance increases is to **benchmark everything**, because it will never be where you thought it would be.

---

Poor man's VBA benchmarking (only accurate to the nearest 1/100th of a second):

```
Public Sub SplitTimer(ByVal printMessage As String, ByRef oldTimer As Double)
    '/ prints message and time diff between current timer and previous timer
    '/ then updates previous timer with current timer

    Dim currentTimer As Double
    currentTimer = Timer()

    Debug.Print printMessage & " - " & (currentTimer - oldTimer) & " s"

    oldTimer = currentTimer

End Sub
```

Then, in your Macros:

```
    Dim timerStore As Double
    timerStore = Timer()

    ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("D" & i).Value
    SplitTimer "B3", timerStore

    ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("E" & i).Value
    SplitTimer "B4", timerStore

    ws2.Range("B5").Value = ws1.Range("F" & i).Value
    SplitTimer "B5", timerStore

    ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("G" & i).Value
    SplitTimer "B6", timerStore
```

And so on. You'll then get a list of how long each section of your code took to execute. In general, there will be one section that's responsible for ~98% of the runtime:

```
'/ (hypothetical output)
B3 - 1.40625 s
B4 - 0 s
B5 - 0 s
B6 - 0.041796875 s
```

Take that operation, split it into smaller pieces, benchmark. Repeat until you've found the source of your slow runtime. Then you can experiment yourself, or take that **very specific** opeation to SO for performance ideas.

---

In your specific case, I have a hunch.

Copy/Pasting actually **doesn't** take a lot of time (per operation). 20 operations in 2 minutes, I'd expect it to be less than 1% of runtime. What takes time is all the **Events** that trigger when you change a worksheet.

In particular, every calculation is going to re-calculate every time you paste a new value in.

Try this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 4 To selection

    '/ Paste operations

    '/ Paste operations

    '/ Paste operations

    Application.Calculate '/ we only calculate once per iteration, when everything's set up and ready.

    ws1.Range("AO" & i).Value = ws2.Range("M4").Value

Next i
```

And see if it makes a noticeable difference to your performance.

---

Comment: And don't forget to add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end to turn it back on.